# Java methods getting euclidean distance

Tags: java, methods, euclidean-distance

```
public class Point
{ 
// Placeholders for xcoordinate, ycoordinate, and quadrants
int xcoord = 0;
int ycoord =0;
double distance = 0.0;
String quadrant = ("NW");


//moveUp changes the y coordinate 
void moveUp (int x) {
    int moveUp = ycoord + x;
    ycoord= moveUp;
    System.out.println(moveUp);
    }
// moveDown changes the y coordinate    
void moveDown (int y){
    int moveDown = ycoord - y;
    ycoord =moveDown;
    System.out.println(moveDown);}
// moveLeft changes the x coordinate    
void moveLeft (int f){
    int moveLeft = xcoord -f ;
    xcoord = moveLeft;
    System.out.println(moveLeft);}
// moveRight changes the x coordinate   
void moveRight (int h) {
    int moveRight  = xcoord +h ;
    xcoord = moveRight;
    System.out.println(moveRight);}

//  This takes the y coordinate and the xcoordinate and places it into a quadrant. Then it returns the quadrant.
String quadrant () {    
    if (xcoord >= 0 && ycoord  >=0){
        return quadrant = ("NE"); }
    else if ( xcoord < 0 && ycoord < 0 ) {
        return quadrant = ("SW");}
    else if (xcoord <0 && ycoord >0 ){
        return quadrant = ("NW");}
    else if (xcoord >0 && ycoord <0){
        return quadrant = ("SE");}
    else {
        return quadrant = ("Origin");}  
}
//euclidean distance (?)
Point distance (Point other) {
    Point result = new Point(); 
    result.ycoord = Math.abs (ycoord - other.ycoord);
    result.xcoord = Math.abs (xcoord- other.xcoord);    
    result.distance = Math.sqrt((result.ycoord)*(result.ycoord) +(result.xcoord)*(result.xcoord));
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;

    }

}
```

Here is the whole code. What I'm having trouble with is for some reason my distance method isn't working properly and I don't know why. It returns `Point@24a42c89`, instead of any number. Please let me know why it is returning this instead of a number. Thanks so much. I'm a beginner and have little knowledge on Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method returns a Point because you return `result` which is an instance of Point. If you want a double (value) for the distance you should do it this way:

```
//euclidean distance (?)
double distance (Point other) {
    Point result = new Point(); 
    result.ycoord = Math.abs (ycoord - other.ycoord);
    result.xcoord = Math.abs (xcoord- other.xcoord);    
    result.distance = Math.sqrt((result.ycoord)*(result.ycoord) +(result.xcoord)*(result.xcoord));
    System.out.println(result);
    return result.distance; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `Point result` entirely and store all the calculations as `double`s.

Comment: the return type is Point so I feel it is necessary

Comment: @KickButtowski Feel what is necessary?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I totally agree with you but it is up to the op what accept :)

Answer (score 8):

You are getting a `Point` as a result because you are returning a `Point` object. There is no reason to declare a `Point` object when calculating the distance between two points. The results of all calculations here are **numbers**, so declare all variables as `double`:

```
double distance (Point other) {
    double deltaX = ycoord - other.ycoord;
    double deltaY = xcoord - other.xcoord;
    double result = Math.sqrt(deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY);
    return result; 
}
```

Note there is no need for `Math.abs()` since squaring two numbers always results in a non-negative number.

This also removes the need of storing a `distance` value in every point. This should make sense because a point is a pair of (x, y) coordinates, but does **not** have an inherent distance. Rather "distance" is a relationship between two points.

Answer (score 0):

In you distance function

```
Point distance (Point other) {
     ...

     rest of your code 
     ...
    System.out.println(result); <-- you have tired to print out the object
    return result;

    }
```

to rectify your issue you need to print out the filed of the object that you are looking for which is `distance`

```
 System.out.println(result.distance);
```

One suggestion

you can change return type `distance` function from `Point` to `int`

why?

Because return the object `Point` does not represent the value of distance

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you explain further?

Comment: Okay! that makes more sense! Thank you for the help!